# Profiling a Java EE Application

Tags: performance, profiling, jprobe

What does a Profiler do exactly?

I ran the JProbe profiler on my Java EE Application.
For now I selected Performance Analysis only. When I investigated the code, it showed how many times each method gets called and how much time it took. It gave me a clear view of these things.

Now my question is, what in general does a profiler do exactly? The only thing it seems to do is showing how many times a method is called and how much time each method took?

Does Profiling a Java EE application indeed only means this thing? (In the concern of Performance Analyses only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A profiler can tell you lots of useful things, in addition to traces and method timings:

- The state of the heap and its generations in real time: perm, eden, etc.
- Created threads and their states
- CPU usage
- Number of instances of each class

I like to use Visual VM 1.3.3 with all the plugins installed.  I use the Oracle/Sun JVMs, so it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add..Profiling is general concept not only restricted to Java or Java EE. 
It is a dynamic analysis of your program.

- what does it do? you can check on profiler application.
- how does it help: Helps you to optimize your program and trouble shoot cases such as Out of memory and dead lock which is not possible with the routine debugging techniques (printlns and debugger).